# is there a packagemanager for Xcode? (like NuGet)

Tags: ios, xcode, nuget

I'm searching for an easy way to reuse code in xcode 4.3. Is there a tool like NuGet available for Xcode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checkout [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods), An Objective-C library dependency manager.

Answer (score 1):

See this project for an XCode package manager:

[Alcatraz package manager](https://github.com/mneorr/Alcatraz)

It is currently limited to the listed plugins.